# Does leveldb generate Bloom Filter every 4KB or 2KB of Data Block?

Tags: c++, leveldb, rocksdb

I have read the source code of leveldb. I found that when the size of Data Block reaches 4KB, it will flush the Data Block and call `FilterBlockBuilder::StartBlock()` to generate filter.

```
void TableBuilder::Add(const Slice& key, const Slice& value) {
  // ...
  const size_t estimated_block_size = r->data_block.CurrentSizeEstimate();
  if (estimated_block_size >= r->options.block_size) {
    Flush();
  }
}

void TableBuilder::Flush() {
  // ...
  if (r->filter_block != nullptr) {
    r->filter_block->StartBlock(r->offset);
  }
}
```

`FilterBlockBuilder::StartBlock()` calls `GenerateFilter()` `block_offset/2KB` times. For example, when block_offset is 4KB, it will call `GenerateFilter()` 2 times.

However, after the first call of `GenerateFilter()`, `keys` and `starts` are both empty. As a result, the second call only generates an empty filter and adds the same filter offset to `filter_offsets`.

Does leveldb generate 2 Bloom Filter each of which is for 2KB part of Data Block, or 1 Bloom Filter for the whole 4KB Data Block with another empty filter?

```
void FilterBlockBuilder::StartBlock(uint64_t block_offset) {
  uint64_t filter_index = (block_offset / kFilterBase);
  assert(filter_index >= filter_offsets_.size());
  while (filter_index > filter_offsets_.size()) {
    GenerateFilter();
  }
}

void FilterBlockBuilder::GenerateFilter() {
  const size_t num_keys = start_.size();
  // ****** My Comment: will the second call in StartBlock always trigger this?
  if (num_keys == 0) {
    // Fast path if there are no keys for this filter
    filter_offsets_.push_back(result_.size());
    return;
  }

  // Make list of keys from flattened key structure
  start_.push_back(keys_.size());  // Simplify length computation
  tmp_keys_.resize(num_keys);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_keys; i++) {
    const char* base = keys_.data() + start_[i];
    size_t length = start_[i + 1] - start_[i];
    tmp_keys_[i] = Slice(base, length);
  }

  // Generate filter for current set of keys and append to result_.
  filter_offsets_.push_back(result_.size());
  policy_->CreateFilter(&tmp_keys_[0], static_cast<int>(num_keys), &result_);

  tmp_keys_.clear();
  keys_.clear();
  start_.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

4k Data Block will call `GenerateFilter()` twice and generate two BloomFilter items. Both of two BloomFilter item are same. see below code

https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/aa5479bbf47e9df86e0afbb89e6246085f22cdd4/table/filter_block.cc#L51-L57

```
void FilterBlockBuilder::GenerateFilter() {
  const size_t num_keys = start_.size();
  if (num_keys == 0) {
    // Fast path if there are no keys for this filter
    filter_offsets_.push_back(result_.size());
    return;
  }
  
  ...
```

When called `GenerateFilter()` second time, num_keys will equal 0, will append same offset of first call.

Don't know why it's designed that way